# Solr & AJAX setting response query correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, solr

I am using [Solr's JSON output for AJAX example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJSON) as a basis for my project. However I have modified things by adding a drop-down menu in the form and added faceting to the params.

Params:

```
function getstandardargs() {
    var params = [
        'wt=json'
        ,'facet=true'
        ,'facet.field=brand1'
        ,'facet.field=brand2'
        ,'facet.field=brand3'
        ,'facet.field=brand4'
        ,'facet.limit=2'
        ];
```

Drop- down menu:

```
<form name="f1" onsubmit='xmlhttpPost("/solr/select"); return false;'>
  <p>query: <input name="query" type="text">  
  <select id="Entity">
  <option value="brand1">Universal</option>
  <option value="brand2">Paramount</option>
  <option value="brand3">Fox</option>
  <option value="brand4">Sony</option>
</select> 
  <input value="Go" type="submit"></p>
```

I am trying to add the drop-down value to my facet query result as such:

```
var rsp = eval("("+str+")");
var c=document.getElementById("Entity");
cat=c.options[c.selectedIndex].value;
var output=rsp.facet_counts.facet_fields;
html += "Entity: " + output+'.'+cat;
```

My facet response sends back: **Entity: [object Object].Universal**. How do I add the drop-down value to the response query correctly so Solr can actually return the proper facet values? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will undoubtedly reduce the complexity of this problem by using a library for your ajax request because:

- you can easily do the dom manipulation required to turn them into
  select options
- you can send the request arbitrarily with the expectation to get back an actual json object
- you can avoid the use of `eval`

And since you said your response is "Entity: [object Object].Universal", can you try to use `console.log( output );` to tell us what is returned in the object, officially? there's a possibility that by concatenating strings with an object, you're messing up the output object

if it is in fact an object, you can access it iteratively like this:

```
for(var x in rsp.facet_counts.facet_fields) {
    //rsp.facet_counts.facet_fields[x]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. console.log shows the window < Objects correctly in firebug: brand1 ["Eve2", 10, "RHCP", 6] brand2 ["Black_Keys", 6, "White_Stripe", 5] brand3 ["SoaD", 5, "BoB", 3] brand4 ["Doors", 3, "Cage_Elephant", 2]. If I statically insert any of the 4 brands (rsp.facet_counts.facet_fields.brand1) I get the correct facet results from Solr. However, I cant figure out why adding brand1 dynamically from the entity drop-down as a var with a '+' coughs on me...

Comment: you're not doing it dynamically, you're coercing the type incorrectly. the proper way to make those items is to create a for loop where for each array member you reference your rsp.facet_counts.facet_fields object. for(var x in rsp.facet_counts.facet_fields) { //do something with rsp.facet_counts.facet_fields[x] }